# Невстраиваемые копии конструкторов и деструкторов. При чем тут указатели на функции и разрушение именно объектов в массиве?

Tags: c++

В книге "Скотт Мэйерс Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных способов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ" в правиле 30 есть такие строчки:

> Иногда компилятор генерирует тела встроенной функции, даже если ничто
>   не мешает ее  встроить.  Например,  если  ваша  программа  получает 
>   адрес  встроенной  функции,  то компилятор,  как  правило,  должен 
>   сгенерировать  настоящее  тело  функции.  Как  иначе он может получить
>   адрес функции, если ее не существует? В совокупности с тем фактом, что
>   обычно компиляторы не выполняют встраивание, если функция вызывается
>   по указателю,это  значит, что вызовы  строенных функций могут 
>   встраиваться или не встраиваться в зависимости от того, как к ней
>   производится обращение:

```
inline void f() {...} // предположим, что компилятор может встроить вызовы f
void (*pf)() = f; // pf указывает на f
...
f(); // этот вызов будет встроенным, потому что он
// «нормальный»
pf(); // этот вызов, вероятно, не будет встроен, потому что
// функция вызвана по указателю
```

> Призрак невстраиваемых inline-функций может преследовать вас, даже
>   если вы никогда не  используете  указателей  на  функции,  потому  что
>   указатели  на  функции  может запрашивать не только программист.
>   Иногда компилятор генерирует невстраиваемые копии конструкторов и
>   деструкторов так, что они запрашивают  указатели на функции во время
>   конструирования и разрушения объектов в массивах.

не понятно при чем тут указатели на функции и разрушение именно объектов в массиве.

Comment: Надо бы побольше цитату, а то непонятно в каком контексте это сказано. Не у всех есть самая старая книга Мейерса чтобы самому посмотреть (у меня вот нет, оказывается).

Comment: @freim, держите [мою](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/C/Addison.Wesley.Effective.CPP.3rd.Edition.May.2005.pdf). Страница 137, первый абзац

Comment: По-моему это все можно записать куда короче: наличие или отсутсвие `inline` никак не влияет на то, будет ли функция встраиваться или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мейерс скорее всего просто ссылается на какую-то известную ему реализацию, в которой конструкция и деструкция объектов-массивов внутренне делается через вызов некоей скрытой универсальной функции "конструктор массива" или "деструктор массива", набор параметров которой включает *указатель* на конструктор/деструктор единичного элемента. Так как конструкторы могут быть параметризованы, с конструкторами такая реализация возможна только в частных случаях (например, при вызове конструктора по умолчанию), а с деструкторами все намного проще.

Намного лучшим примером был бы пример с деструкцией статических объектов в программе: так как информация о том, какие объекты были сконструированы, а какие нет, (и в каком порядке) появляется только в время выполнения, для последующей правильной деструкуции таких объектов они во время выполнения обычно регистрируются в некоем едином списке, содержащем *указатели* на их деструкторы. (При этом понятно, что регистрировать в таком списке массивы разумнее не поэлементно, а как единое целое, с запоминанием количества элементов и размера элемента.)

Возьмем, к примеру такой код

```
struct NonTrivial
{
  ~NonTrivial() 
  {
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

void foo()
{
  static NonTrivial A[1000];
}

int main() 
{
  if (rand() > 0) foo();
}
```

В такой ситуации компилятор MSVC++ генерирует код, который в процессе выполнения регистрирует в некоем списке параметры успешно созданного статического массива, а затем для его удаления при завершении программы передает эти параметры в универсальную внутреннюю функцию

```
`eh vector destructor iterator'(void * ptr, 
                                unsigned __int64 size, 
                                unsigned __int64 count, 
                                void(*)(void *) destructor)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

которая, как вы видите, на вход принимает *указатель на деструктор*. В случае удаления статических объектов компилятор вынужден пользоваться такими функциями по вышеуказанным причинам.

Возникает вопрос: а воспользуется ли компилятор этой же функцией в ситуации, когда "всё ясно" уже на стадии компиляции, т.е. для удаления обычного автоматического массива?

```
...
int main() 
{
  NonTrivial B[512];
}
```

Проверяем... Пользуется!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вам готовый пример именно того, о чем по-видимому ведет речь Мейерс в процитированной вами части текста.

(Более того, мое утверждение о том, что здесь "вся ясно" уже на стадии компиляции является неверным. Какой деструктор надо вызывать для элементов этого массива, конечно, ясно. Но в процессе конструирования массива в некий непредсказуемый момент может произойти исключение. То есть *количество элементов*, которые надо деструктировать является величиной времени выполнения. Возможно, именно это является поводом для компилятора не гнаться за эффективностью встроенного деструктора, а пользоваться все той же параметризованной функцией.)

---

Компилятор GCC для решения такой задачи поступает по-другому: вместо одной универсальной параметризованной функции-уничтожителя, он генерирует индивидуальные функции-уничтожители для каждого статического массива. В каждой такой функции жестко прошиты характеристики массива, включая его адрес и размер. (Эти функции имеют имена вида `__tcf_0`, `__tcf_1` и т.д.)

Регистрация таких функций во время выполнения и вызовы таких функций при завершении программы делаются через указатели. Но уже внутри такой функции вызов деструктора элемента в цикле уничтожения массива может запросто встраиваться.

Comment: мне кажется что если ты прав, то Мейерс слишком сильно усложнил примеры для объяснения правила, очень глубоко залез, или я не прав, это должен знать программист С++?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Как я сказал выше, Мейерсу лучше было бы упомянуть деструкцию статических объектов (любых, не массивов). Это намного более "осязамый" и логичный пример. И задача удаления только тех объектов, которые уже сконструировались - это естественная задача, которую должен знать и понимать каждый С++ программист. А его пример с массивами - это скорее ссылка на глубокую деталь реализации, которую он даже не удосужился объяснить. (Да, Мейерс ведет речь именно о том, что я описал. Но пример - плохой.)

Comment: мне тоже так показалось, что чего то не договаривает он.

Comment: "с деструкцией статических объектов" почему именно статических?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Нет, именно статических. Именно статические объекты создаются в непредсказуемые (на стадии компиляции) моменты времени. Поэтому для их уничтожения приходится строить некие структуры времени выполнения и использовать указатели на деструкторы. С автоматическими объектами [почти] все ясно на стадии компиляции. С автоматическими объектами необходимости в указателях на деструкторы обычно нет.

Comment: Голова кругом идет от такой инфы, Спасибо тебе за столь развернутое разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось найти книгу и покопаться.

Короче, смысл в том, что компилятор может не встраивать функцию, если используется указатель на нее. Потому что у встроенной функции как такового адреса нет. Так что вызов через указатель приводит к тому, что этот вызов будет невстроенным.

А далее Мейерс говорит, что такой вызов по указателю не обязательно явный, написанный программистом, и что такой вызов по указателю может быть в сгенерированном компилитором конструкторе или деструкторе, так что вы не можете гарантированность встраиваемости только потому, что сами явно не вызываете функцию через указатель...

Указатель при том, что если есть функция и используется указатель на нее - то она не будет встроенной. (Разве что она будет встроенной в других местах, а тем, где использован вызов через указатель - нет...)

Так понятно?

Для более точного и подробного ответа нужен оригинал книги; допускаю, что переводчик мог и не так перевести что-то...

Посмотрел оригинал. Нет, вроде все переведено прилично. А массив просто при том, что при, скажем, циклическом удалении в массиве может использоваться указатель на деструктор - как пример такого поведения, не более того.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: понятно, не понятно почему он упомянул про массивы.

Comment: по ходу дошло, про массивы он упомянул потому что в массиве много объектов и соответственно вызовов деструкторов, и нет смысла встраивать каждый деструктор, может их будет несколько тысяч, лучше использовать указатель. правильно? то же самое и с уиклами, может быть милион итераций вызовов функций в теле цикла.

Comment: @Stanislav Petrov: Нет, конечно. Во-первых , удаление или создание массива будет скорее всего выполнено циклом. Поэтому ничего страшного от встраивания конструктора/деструктора в тело этого цикла не произойдет. Во-вторых, даже если компилятор решил их не встраивать, все равно не ясно при чем здесь вдруг "указатели на функции". Так что нет, имеется в виду что-то совсем другое.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, никто не мешает транслятору встраивать функции там, где их можно встраивать. И одновременно создавать отдельные копии тех же функций там, где нужно брать адрес функции или метода или деструктора и конструктора. Ну будет небольшое раздувание кода, ну и что? Все равно при встраивании функций происходит раздувание кода, но на это идут ради увеличения быстродействия. И тут такая же ситуация.